# Failed to build wheel for imread

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to install the deepspectrum package via pip. The first error showed that I needed to install the C++ Build Tools, which I did, but I still get this huge error message regarding imread. I tried installing imread seperatly which results in the same error.
I installed pkgconfig and pylibjpeg-libjpeg,  but the error still occurs

Any help is appreciated.

```
    pip install imread
Collecting imread
  Using cached imread-0.7.4.tar.gz (151 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: imread
  Building wheel for imread (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\U
sers\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\
\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if
 os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f
.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bi58x7uq'
       cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\
  Complete output (130 lines):
  Der Befehl "pkg-config" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
  konnte nicht gefunden werden. (Command "pkg-config" is either misspelled or can't be found)
  running bdist_wheel
  ....
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\imread
  copying imread\ijrois.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\imread
  ....
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread\lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /
MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -Ic:\users\hp\pych
armprojects\ci-14\venv37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" -Ic:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpimread/_imread.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread/_imread.obj
  _imread.cpp
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/base.h(221): warning C4146: Einem vorzeich
enlosen Typ wurde ein un„rer Minus-Operator zugewiesen. Das Ergebnis ist weiterhin vorzeichenlos.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/base.h(221): warning C4267: "Argument": Ko
nvertierung von "size_t" nach "int", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(20): warning C4996: 'close': The PO
SIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _close. See online help for details.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(23): warning C4267: "Argument": Kon
vertierung von "size_t" nach "unsigned int", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(23): warning C4996: 'read': The POS
IX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _read. See online help for details.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(26): warning C4267: "Argument": Kon
vertierung von "size_t" nach "off_t", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(32): warning C4267: "Argument": Kon
vertierung von "size_t" nach "unsigned int", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(32): warning C4996: 'write': The PO
SIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _write. See online help for details.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/file.h(37): warning C4996: 'lseek': The PO
SIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _lseek. See online help for details.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/numpy.h(75): warning C4244: "return": Konv
ertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib/numpy.h(114): warning C4244: "Argument": K
onvertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/_imread.cpp(100): warning C4267: "Argument": Konvertierung von "size_t" nach "const int", Datenverlust m”glich
  imread/_imread.cpp(104): warning C4996: 'open': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _open
. See online help for details.
  imread/_imread.cpp(297): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "Py_ssize_t" in "unsigned int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/_imread.cpp(297): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "Py_ssize_t" in "const unsigned int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/_imread.cpp(286): warning C4996: 'open': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _open
. See online help for details.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /
MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -Ic:\users\hp\pych
armprojects\ci-14\venv37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" -Ic:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpimread/lib/formats.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread/lib/formats.obj
  formats.cpp
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\base.h(221): warning C4146: Einem vorzeich
enlosen Typ wurde ein un„rer Minus-Operator zugewiesen. Das Ergebnis ist weiterhin vorzeichenlos.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\base.h(221): warning C4267: "Argument": Ko
nvertierung von "size_t" nach "int", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /
MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -Ic:\users\hp\pych
armprojects\ci-14\venv37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" -Ic:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpimread/lib/numpy.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread/lib/numpy.obj
  numpy.cpp
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\base.h(221): warning C4146: Einem vorzeich
enlosen Typ wurde ein un„rer Minus-Operator zugewiesen. Das Ergebnis ist weiterhin vorzeichenlos.
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\base.h(221): warning C4267: "Argument": Ko
nvertierung von "size_t" nach "int", Datenverlust m”glich
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\numpy.h(75): warning C4244: "return": Konv
ertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\imread\lib\numpy.h(114): warning C4244: "Argument": K
onvertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/lib/numpy.cpp(8): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/lib/numpy.cpp(8): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "npy_intp" in "const int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/lib/numpy.cpp(9): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "npy_intp" in "int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  imread/lib/numpy.cpp(9): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "npy_intp" in "const int", m”glicher Datenverlust
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /
MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MahotasImread_PyArray_API_Symbol -DIMREAD_EXCLUDE_WEBP=1 -Ic:\users\hp\pych
armprojects\ci-14\venv37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\include" -Ic:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpimread/lib/_bmp.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread/lib/_bmp.obj
  _bmp.cpp
  ...
  imread/lib/_jpeg.cpp(10): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "jpeglib.h": No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' fail
ed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imread
  Running setup.py clean for imread
Failed to build imread
Installing collected packages: imread
    Running setup.py install for imread ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\
\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppDat
a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__)
if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zmh54tzq\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\include\site\python3.7\imread'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18a2zq5_\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\
    Complete output (130 lines):
    Der Befehl "pkg-config" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
    konnte nicht gefunden werden.
    running install
    running build
    ...
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\imread\lib
    ...
    imread/lib/_jpeg.cpp(10): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "jpeglib.h": No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' fa
iled with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools,
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __
file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-18a2zq5_\\imread_7cd8a10db9674220b0c80f4dfa42a2d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize,
 '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().repl
ace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rec
ord-zmh54tzq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\ci-14\venv37\include\
site\python3.7\imread' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You need to install visual studio C++ tools

Comment: I have already installed C++ tools as mentioned above, the error message is different from before the installation and it does find the C++ tools now.